Cessna 152 rattling/clanking noise in tail?
Going on a flight in a c152. Upon taxiing we hear a relatively loud and noticeable clanking/banging noise from what sounds like the tail. Never heard it before till this flight. Upon takeoff the noise gets more profound. Almost sounded as if the fuel cap wasn’t secure and the metal was banging. We requested to come back and land and upon inspection on the ground I could not find any external issues. I am unsure what this noise could be but it most definitely sounded like something broke off and was banging around somewhere in the tail section of the aircraft. It is a training aircraft so of course it gets a lot of wear and tear on it but I am unable to diagnose the issue. Lose bolt? Lose cable? Note that there were no issues with the integrity of the flight controls. Any help/ideas would be appreciated.

My idea is to have an A&P inspect it.

Did you perform a pre-flight inspection?

When this has happened to me it was a belt hanging out the door and the clasp banging against the side - but as it sounds like there were two of you onboard and I doubt one of you didnt have a belt on I doubt this is the answer.

Was the banging noise due to movement, or did you hear it when stationary? Did it change when you throttled up or down?

Noise was only prominent when aircraft was moving.

You are clearly not an aircraft mechanic. Stop operating the aircraft and take it to someone who is, have that person investigate and correct the issue. I am astonished you actually took off while hearing that noise coming from the tail.

@Jamiec I have also had it happen with a backpack strap that was hanging a few inches out of the door. It made quite a noise for a few minutes before I realized and pulled the backpack in.
